# How can I securely link to files in a ColdFusion application without hosting them?

Tags: coldfusion, filepath, network-drive, file-security

I am building an application in ColdFusion as part of my job. This application basically creates tickets for issues. On a shared network drive there are folders that correspond to the ticket numbers with files pertaining to that ticket.

However, there are two different types of users: the first which create the tickets and have access to all of these files on the shared drive, and a second which should only have access to the files that pertain to a ticket which they are included/CC'd on. These files contain sensitive information and so they cannot all be shared among this second type of user, and they also cannot have the full path to which they could navigate through to get to other folders and such.

That brings me to my next problem, these files are very large in many cases and so my boss does not want to put these on any of our own servers (which host our applications and such) nor does he want me to even copy them temporarily to our server to allow download of these files, and then delete them due to the "latency" as he calls it.

So at this point, I am looking for options of how to make files that are specific to a ticket number available to only certain people. This could be done through the ColdFusion application in the way that it links to them, or also through changing some of the structure of the folders and shared drive itself. Does anyone have a good method that could be used for this?

If anything is unclear, I'm sorry, just ask and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Step 1 - make sure the account running ColdFusion has access to the file locations.

Comment: The ColdFusion account has access. I'm able to get directory/file information through the application already.

Comment: You say big files.  Sometimes files are so big that attempting to open them with CF causes java heap space errors,  You might want to test that out.

Comment: Well, they're around 15 megabtyes anywhere up to 100 megabytes from what I can tell, along with a few other smaller files.

Comment: Are these all documents or are we talking any sort of file here? from a download to something that might be displayed in the browser potentially.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is within the same network and can access the shared folder, you could use an a href with a unc path to the file as Sharepoint does